# How to make mypy complain about assigning an Any to an int

Tags: python-3.x, type-hinting, mypy, typechecking, static-typing

`mypy --strict` dutifully complains about the following code:

```
from typing import Any, Dict

def main() -> None:
    my_str: str = 'hello'
    my_int: int = my_str

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

by outputting:

```
error: Incompatible types in assignment (expression has type "str", variable has type "int")
```

However the following code is accepted without any error:

```
from typing import Any, Dict

def main() -> None:
    my_str: Any = 'hello'
    my_int: int = my_str

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Is there an option for `mypy` to make it also reject the second example?

I expect it to do so, because it also rejects the following:

```
from typing import Any, Dict, Union

def main() -> None:
    my_str: Union[int, str] = 'hello'
    my_int: int = my_str

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

with:

```
error: Incompatible types in assignment (expression has type "Union[int, str]", variable has type "int")
```

And in my understanding an `Any` is just the `Union` of all possible types.

Comment: No, why should it reject that? It *can't make any assertions about what `my_str` _might_ be*.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43910979/mypy-error-incompatible-types-in-assignment and read the answer's description of type-checking of `Any`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Mypy error - incompatible types in assignment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43910979/mypy-error-incompatible-types-in-assignment)

Comment: Any means: sorry, I give up, stop tracking this one.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Good question. I added an explanation for my expectation for the question.

Comment: Regarding [`Mypy error - incompatible types in assignment`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43910979/mypy-error-incompatible-types-in-assignment): I don't think that my question is a duplicate of this. I want `mypy` to produce an error. The other question wants an eligible error to go away. ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> And in my understanding an `Any` is just the `Union` of all possible types.

That's not correct. `Any` is an *escape hatch*, an annotation for variables that you want the type checker to ignore. It certainly is not a union.

From the [mypy documentation on `Any`](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/kinds_of_types.html#the-any-type):

> A value with the `Any` type is dynamically typed. Mypy doesn’t know anything about the possible runtime types of such value. Any operations are permitted on the value, and the operations are only checked at runtime. **You can use `Any` as an “escape hatch” when you can’t use a more precise type for some reason.**

(Bold emphasise mine)

It explicitly covers your case:

> `Any` is compatible with every other type, and vice versa. **You can freely assign a value of type Any to a variable with a more precise type**:
>
> ```
> a: Any = None
> s: str = ''
> a = 2     # OK (assign "int" to "Any")
> s = a     # OK (assign "Any" to "str")
> ```
>
> Declared (and inferred) types are ignored (or erased) at runtime. They are basically treated as comments, and thus the above code does not generate a runtime error, even though `s` gets an `int` value when the program is run, while the declared type of `s` is actually `str`!

So the correct approach is to **not use `Any`** if you want the type checker to keep tracking how the value is used. Use a `Union[]`, as you did in your third example, or re-think your data structures to allow for better type hinting. For example, rather than use a dictionary with a union value type, consider using a named tuple or dataclass with explicit fields and a specific type for each field.

Comment: Oh, thank you very much for this very good explanation. This answers my specific question perfectly (since my understanding of `Any` was incorrect), so I accept it. But sadly it does not solve my problem, so I opened a follow-up question to not make things here too confusing: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51696060/how-to-make-mypy-complain-about-assigning-an-any-to-an-int-part-2

Answer (score 0):

For those that read about this later, the actual solution is to use the "disallow any" family of command line flags, as describes in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51696314/1866775).