# How to make mypy complain about assigning an Any to an int (part 2)

Tags: python-3.x, type-hinting, mypy, typechecking, static-typing

(This is a follow-up to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51695484/how-to-make-mypy-complain-about-assigning-an-any-to-an-int).)

My code base is fully statically typed (annotation) but at some points there is the `Any` type, for example because a value was parsed from a JSON string. Here is my minimal example:

```
import json
from typing import Any, Dict, Union

def main() -> None:
    data = json.loads('{"value" = "three"}')
    my_int: int = data['value']

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

`mypy --strict` accepts this code. However I would like to find these places automatically, to take the appropriate security measures.

Is there any possibility to make `mypy` complain about the `my_int: int = data['value']` assignment?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes -- use the "[disallow any](http://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/command_line.html#disallow-any)" family of command line flags.

In this case, I think you want to use specifically `--disallow-any-expr`, though I recommend you also experiment with the other flags.

(These flags are not automatically enabled as a part of `--strict` because they end up causing a lot of false positives on certain codebases, especially ones that make extensive use of untyped libraries.)

---

As an aside, something you may discover is that enabling all of the "disallow any" flags can end up being a little inconvenient, especially if you have a certain region of your code that needs to do a lot of runtime checks.

To help mitigate this, what I personally like to do is have all of the disallow-any flags enabled by default, but disable a few of them for certain modules. You can do this using mypy's [config files](http://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/config_file.html). For example, you could do:

```
[mypy]
# Specify any other global flags you want to customize here
disallow_any_unimported = True
disallow_any_expr = True
disallow_any_decorated = True
disallow_any_explicit = True
disallow_any_generics = True
disallow_subclassing_any = True

[mypy-mymodule.validation]
# Weaken, just for this module
disallow_any_expr = False
```

And run `mypy --strict --config my_config.ini mymodule`.

This config file would disallow the use of `Any` from almost the entire codebase, except within the `validation` module. (And then, I'd go out of my way to add a bunch of unit tests for that specific module to make up for the weakened static type checks.)